# Yellow highlight while using custom Toast in android

Tags: android, android-studio, toast, android-toast

I am trying to implement custom toast and below is the code I wrote and hooked it to a onClickeListner asusual

```
Button customToastButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.add_to_cart);
        customToastButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //get the LayoutInflater and inflate the custom_toast layout
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_toast, (ViewGroup)
                        findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

                //get the TextView from the custom_toast layout
                TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastText);
                text.setText("Item as been added to cart");

                //create the toast object, set display duration,
                //set the view as layout that's inflated above and then call show()
                Toast t = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                t.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.setView(layout);
                t.show();
            }
        });
```

And the code used is highlighted in yellow showing the below error.well it's not showing as a error in logcat and code works fine.The highlightend part also says ' *may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'*

```
Method invocation 'customToastButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
public void onClick(Vi...' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
    This inspection analyzes method control and data flow to report possible conditions that are always true or false, expressions whose value is statically proven to be constant, and situations that can lead to nullability contract violations.
    Variables, method parameters and return values marked as @Nullable or @NotNull are treated as nullable (or not-null, respectively) and used during the analysis to check nullability contracts, e.g. report possible NullPointerException errors.
    More complex contracts can be defined using @Contract annotation, for example:
    @Contract("_, null -> null") — method returns null if its second argument is null 
@Contract("_, null -> null; _, !null -> !null") — method returns null if its second argument is null and not-null otherwise 
@Contract("true -> fail") — a typical assertFalse method which throws an exception if true is passed to it 
    The inspection can be configured to use custom @Nullable
    @NotNull annotations (by default the ones from annotations.jar will be used)
```

I just don't understand the reason causing this error,I kindly request you to have a look at it.
Thankyou in advance

Comment: `findViewById` may return null ... so `customToastButton.setOnClickListener` may produce NPE ... it just a warning ... you may suppress the warning using annotation/comment or doing a null check

Comment: NPE.? anyway to remove the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just check if your `customToastButton` is not null before setting the `OnClickListener`

```
if(customToastButton!=null){
    customToastButton.setOnClickListener(...)
...
}
```

The warning is shown, because if the `Button` does not exist and you continue working with it a `NullPointerException` will be thrown.

Comment: Works like a charm Thank-you for your support it meant a lot to me

Comment: sure no problem! would be great if you could accept the answer as correct :)

Comment: Sure,btw do know anything related to developing a shopping cart in android.? like passing data's hint's would do enough

Comment: sorry, got no experience with that. but there are certainly some pretty good tutorials out there you could have a look at

Comment: Thankyou once again.